# How can I solve this wrong with R.java in android studio?

Tags: android

[when  i try execute my app appear this problem (R.java in red)and the wrong in this ststmant   (public static final int sign-google=0x7f0d009d;), i done rebuild and Build APK, BUT the problem did not solve][1]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtHQm.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable name is illegal.
Use sign_google instead of sign-google